# Load php page without user having to type '.php' in browser

Tags: php

I have a webpage: http://www.somename.com/webapp.php

I'd like users to be able to get to it be simply typing http://www.somename.com/webapp

I know this would work if the page was an html page ('webapp.html').

Any ideas on how I can make this work?  Is there a configuration file I can edit to get the desired behavior?

I have two ideas, but they seem clunky to me:
1) make a webapp.html and have it redirect to webapp.php
2) make webapp.html and iframe webapp.php inside of it

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache with mod_rewrite,  you can add these lines to your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

This will map hostname.com/webstore to hostname.com/webstore.php

Comment: You probably want to check that it's not an existing directory, either.

Answer (score 3):

Easy solution: Make a folder `webapp/`, move your script there and rename it `index.php` ;-)

Comment: I tried this and it worked - it actually made sense to go this route for other reasons too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

This will turn on [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) and automatically look for a matching file when no extension is given.

Comment: Um... if you're using Apache, that is.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  It's on my to-do list to contact godaddy and find out why.  Thanks.